# Firestore on mobile: rules are not enforced on cached data

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have implemented data access control using *Firestore Rules* which works just fine whenever I fetch the data from the database.

However, the access to any data which have been fetched previously is not controlled by the rules on the device.

Imagine a situation when the app switches Firebase users (sign out then sign back with a different Firebase user) or changes any other property which the access control is relying on. Even though I get a proper rejection when I try refreshing the data from the remote database, what is cached on the device is still accessible due to lack of enforcing the rules locally.

This causes potential privacy issues (data from previous user might leak to the new user). When the app designed properly then filtering on the device might minimize the risk, but everybody makes mistakes.
For example you fetch all the transactions which is available to the user based on a Firestore rule which checks a field in each transaction against the user ID. When the user changed and the data is cached the new user will have access to all the transactions in the cache, regardless whether it belongs to him/her or not.
You might argue that this design is flawed and maybe you are right, but making a mistake like this is far too easy.

It would be better simply removing all the cached data when the circumstances are changing radically, like at the time of signing out.
This is possible by calling [Firestore.clearPersistence()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Firestore.html#clearpersistence) method, but there is a big catch: you must restart (cold start) the app because if you have made any access to the DB then this will fail.
Restarting the app from scratch has many drawbacks and might not even be feasible among all circumstances.

Please advise if there was any better way handling this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules are only enforced on the server. They are not enforced on the client.

Even if security rules were enforced on the client, there'd be no guarantee that the newly signed in user can't see the other user's data, as that data is stored in a (relatively easy to find and access) database on the device.

If you want to ensure that the new user can't see the previous user's data, consider having them use different Android/iOS profiles to sign in, which gives them a whole separate workspace. Aside from that clearing the persistence database programmatically or manually is indeed the only other option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain what do you mean on different profiles? Multiple users on the same device on the OS level?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it. I'm actually not sure what devices and OS support it, but that would be the way to prevent data leakage.

Comment: Fair enough, although usually the problem is that one device is shared by multiple users (like tablets) without setting up individual profiles. We must not assume that there won't be any data leak because the users supposed to use the app properly.
Anyway, clearing the cache is the best solution, but it would be nice if it could be done without restarting the app from scratch.

Comment: Agreed that the experience could be better, so I'd definitely recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for improving it.